# Python - Error message: [ json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) ]

Tags: python

I want to extract a directory of data source from a website. And I got nothing but error message below. What am I doing wrong?

The code I made:

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
import requests
import lxml
import json
import pandas as pd
import re
from hyperlink import URL

url = "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/psi-file-depot/prod/annual-open-data-plans-bd-list.json"

response = requests.get(url)
htmlText = response.text

aObject = json.loads(htmlText) 

for idx, item in enumerate(aObject['data']):
    print("{}{}\t{}".format(
        str(idx).rjust(2, ' '),
        item['provider_name_en'].rjust(25, ' '),
        item['provider_url_en']
        )
        )
```

The error message:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python_test\download_json.py", line 14, in <module>
    aObject = json.loads(htmlText)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Opening the URL in the browser I get following error message: `<Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Key>prod/annual-open-data-plans-bd-list.json</Key><RequestId>VGFJ7700NP97AW5R</RequestId><HostId>JCDcflZBUlZNBXUVhctKNBdWvVMmhX6nogPu4MLMJSHsqci7y7z0QbNxJiRkqRp7Y47aNEp7ap0=</HostId></Error>`

Comment: The problem occurs in `json.loads(htmlText)` - `htmlText` probably doesn't contain (only) valid JSON. Have you tried printing the value and having a look at it?

Comment: Thank you so much gentlemen for your prompt assistance. By the responses I just found the problems with the code and fixed it.